# Referenced parameters in C++

Tags: c++, reference

this is more like an ethical question:

if i have the following code:

```
void changeInt(int& value)
{
value = 7;
}
```

and i do:

```
int number = 3;
changeInt(number);
```

number will have value 7

I know that when the new stack frame will be created for changeInt function, new variables will be created and &value will point to number.

My concern here is that the caller, if it's not paying attention , can be fooled by thinking that is passing by value which actually, on the function frame , a reference will be created.

I know he can look in the header files and it's a perfect legitimate expression but still I find it unethical a bit :)

i think this should be somehow marked and enforced by syntax. Like in C# where you have ref keyword.

What do you guys think ?

Comment: To make it more clear pass by pointer instead. Then the caller needs to pass `&number`.

Comment: @jt_reed Caller should get an editor or an IDE that shows him the function signature. It's enough even to remember the parameter types without references and embedding the parameter types in the function name e.g. `changeInt` is a bit clumsy.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the author documenting the function and/or the programmer reading the docs, right?

Comment: I don't think ethics means what you think it means...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things where references are less clear than pointers. However, using pointers may lead to something like this:

```
changeInt(NULL);
```

when they actually should have done:

```
changeInt(&number);
```

which is just as bad. If the function is as clearly named as this, it's hardly a mystery that it actually changes the value passed in.

Another solution is of course to do:

```
int calculateNewInt(/* may need some input */)
{
   return 7; 
}
```

now

```
int number = 3;
...
number = calculateNewInt();
```

is quite obviously (potentially) changing `number`.

But if the name of the function "sounds like it changes the input value", then it's definitely fair to change the value. If in doubt, read the documentatin. If you write code that has local variables that you don't want to alter, make them `const`.

```
const int number = 3;
changeInt(number);    /* Makes an error */
```

(Of course, that means the number is not changeable elsewhere either).

Answer (score 0):

> I know he can look in the header files and it's a perfect legitimate expression but still I find it unethical a bit :)

I think that's perfectly normal and part of the language. Actually, this is one of the bad things of C and C++: you have to check the headers all the time when dealing with an unknown API, since when calling a function you don't pass by reference explicitly.

That's not the case for all system languages though. IIRC Rust makes it obligatory to pass references explicitly.